# Using VBA/Macro in Excel to reformat report. Moving records in single column, multiple row format to single row, multiple columns format

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with a system that reports user data into two columns:  Column A has the fields (9 total per record) and Column B has the corresponding user data.

- Column A looks like this:

  1. Last Name:
  2. First Name:
  3. Middle Name:
  4. Card Number:
  5. Employee Ref:
  6. Personal Details:
  7. Associate Number:
  8. Location Name:
  9. Status:

The formatting on this report has the fields repeated for each record, meaning that row 10 will be blank, and row 11 will be Last Name:, row 12 will be First Name:, etc.  This format results in very lengthy reports that are difficult to manage.

Another complication to this report concerns null values.  Fields with null values are excluded from the report.  For example, a record that does not have a Location Name will exclude the Location Name: field altogether.  The result of the missing field is a record that is 8 rows instead of the the normal 9 rows.  Some of these records are missing multiple fields, on account of null values.

I am looking for an elegant way to reformat this report.  Specifically, I'm looking for...
-The fields in Column A become Column headers (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I).
-The data in Column B is moved onto a single row, aligned with the corresponding field headers.

The report I'm currently looking at has 3730 records.  However, the system outputs a file that is 43906 rows (including blank rows).  I'd like to get this report to 3731 rows (1 row for field headers + 3730 records).

Any assistance with reformatting this report would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

pheidias

Here is some sample data of 3 records:
•   Last Name:  #1

•   First Name: Security

•   Middle Name:    Badge

•   Card Number:    100

•   Employee Ref:   Security

•   Personal Details:   none

•   Associate Number:   N/A

•   Location Name:  HQ

•   Status: Contractor / Temp

•

•   Last Name:  Doe

•   First Name: John

•   Middle Name:

•   Card Number:    101

•   Employee Ref:

•

•   Last Name:  Deere

•   First Name: John

•   Middle Name:

•   Card Number:    102

•   Employee Ref:

•   Status: Associate

Comment: Show the data rather than just describing it

Comment: ako - I added 3 sample records to end of original comment.  Please tell me if you need more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Place the following routine into a standard code module:

```
Sub pheidias()
    Dim c&, i&, t, v, w
    With ActiveSheet.[a1]
        v = .Resize(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 2)
    End With
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 9)
    t = Split(".Last Name.First Name.Middle Name.Card Number.Employee Ref.Personal Details.Associate Number.Location Name.Status.", ".")
    For i = 1 To 9
        w(1, i) = t(i)
    Next
    c = 2
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If Len(v(i, 1)) Then
            w(c, (InStr("lafimicaempeaslost", LCase$(Left$(v(i, 1), 2))) - 1) / 2 + 1) = v(i, 2)
        Else
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next
    [e1].Resize(UBound(w), UBound(w, 2)) = w
End Sub
```

Note: this routine assumes that the data start in cell A1 and that only ONE blank row separates each of the source report groups.

Note: the location of the output can be edited in the last line. The upper left-hand corner of the output report currently defaults to cell E1.

**UPDATE**

Try this also. The two versions are really the same, but the one below is probably easier to read...

```
Sub pheidias()
    Dim c&, i&, v, w

    With ActiveSheet.[a1]
        v = .Resize(.Item(.Parent.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, 2)
    End With

    ReDim w(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 9)

    w(1, 1) = "Last Name"
    w(1, 2) = "First Name"
    w(1, 3) = "Middle Name"
    w(1, 4) = "Card Number"
    w(1, 5) = "Employee Ref"
    w(1, 6) = "Personal Details"
    w(1, 7) = "Associate Number"
    w(1, 8) = "Location Name"
    w(1, 9) = "Status"

    c = 2
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        If Len(v(i, 1)) Then
            Select Case LCase$(Left$(v(i, 1), 2))
                Case "la":  w(c, 1) = v(i, 2)
                Case "fi":  w(c, 2) = v(i, 2)
                Case "mi":  w(c, 3) = v(i, 2)
                Case "ca":  w(c, 4) = v(i, 2)
                Case "em":  w(c, 5) = v(i, 2)
                Case "pe":  w(c, 6) = v(i, 2)
                Case "as":  w(c, 7) = v(i, 2)
                Case "lo":  w(c, 8) = v(i, 2)
                Case "st":  w(c, 9) = v(i, 2)
            End Select
        Else
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next

    [e1].Resize(UBound(w), UBound(w, 2)) = w

End Sub
```

Comment: Impressive code.  The code worked very well when each record had the correct number of lines.  However, when I ran this on the full report, I was getting Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.  The code errored out when the sheet has a record do not have all 9 fields. Can this code be augmented to add in any missing fields?

Comment: @pheidias Hi. Perhaps my first version of the answer may work better in that case. I've just updated my answer to include that at the bottom. It is longer, but also less cryptic. Please let me know how it fares. If you are still having problems, I can work with you to sort it.

Comment: @pheidias Thanks for posting your sample data. Using that I was able to track down what the problem is. I have updated both versions of my answer. It's a line near the top that starts with: `ReDim w(1 to...` Please try the update on the shorter answer at top first.

Comment: @pheidias Any success?